# HTTPS session lost/not exists

Tags: php, session, https

I've got a problem with my login to administration on website with https protocol. If I log in, it will write me my error message "You are not allowed. back to login page". Where should be problem? It's working on http protocol fine :-( Thanks for your help!

**index.php with login**

```
<?php
    include_once "../inc/connection.php";

    if(isset($_POST['go'])){
        $usr = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, htmlentities($_POST['u_name']));
        $psw = SHA1($_POST['u_pass']) ; //using SHA1() to encrypt passwords  
        $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$usr' AND password='$psw'";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1){
            session_start();   
            $_SESSION['log'] = 'in';
            header('location:photos.php');
        } else {
            $error = 'Wrong details. Please try again'; 
        }
    }
?>
```

**and photos.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();

if( !isset($_SESSION['log']) || ($_SESSION['log'] != 'in') ){
    echo "You are not allowed. <a href='index.php'>back to login page</a>";
    exit();
}

if(isset($_GET['log']) && ($_GET['log']=='out')){
    session_destroy();
    header('location:index.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: session always start on the top on file. write session_start() in the first line of file

Comment: you mean in index.php?

Comment: yes. you should write session_start() on the top of index file. Always remember to start it on the top

Comment: @urfusion it doesn't matters where you locate the `session_start()` method. The only thing you should consider is to not have any output before calling the method.

Comment: @user3216673 your login system is not secure! You should always check if the logged in user is a valid user in database. You must keep the username and the crypted password in the session.

Comment: have a look on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm

Comment: I moved session_start(); to the beggining of the index.php and it stil doesn't works :(

Comment: I've inserted `var_dump($_SESSION)` in files index.php and photos.php, but the output is always an empty array - `array(0) {}` :(

Comment: has you use session in connection.php?

Comment: nope, is it neccesary?

Comment: no, just asking. do one thing. write $_SESSION['login'] = "working"; just after you start session. and check session maintaining this value or not?
and remember to start session just after php tags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89809/discussion-between-urfusion-and-user3216673).

Answer (score 0):

I think you session path is not writable.
try

```
ini_set("session.save_handler", "files");
session_save_path ("/tmp");
```